# Ajax select multiple

Tags: php, ajax

Прекрасно работает без multiple, подскажите как все таки сделать так, что бы в можно было передавать через запятую $_POST['option']. Спасибо!

```
<select name="usert[]" multiple onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>    
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<p id="print-ajax"></p>

    

<script type="text/javascript">
            function fetch_select(val){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: './ajax/select_infor.php',
                    datatype:'json',
                    data: {option:val},
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#print-ajax').html(response);//This will print you result

  }
  
                });
            }
        </script>
```

select_infor.php:

```
echo $_POST['option'];
```

Comment: Передавать на сервер? А зачем? В виде массива удобнее же

Answer (score 0):

У вас не работает данный код с `multiple`, так как в этом случае передается массив, а не скалярное значение. Чтобы проверить значение `$_POST['usert']` используйте функцию `var_dump()`. Чтобы вывести значение этой переменной, используйте цикл `foreach`.

```php
$options = !empty($_POST['usert']) ? $_POST['usert'] : array();
foreach ($options as $option) {
    echo $option;
}
```

Comment: Не проще воспользоваться [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php)?

Comment: @mepihindeveloper, можно воспользоваться чем угодно. Я не знаю уровня знаний автора и задачи, которую он решает, поэтому написал базовый пример.

Comment: не лучший совет по "базовым" моментам. Лучше же сразу советовать пользоваться функциями языка

Comment: @mepihindeveloper, это и есть самые базовые функции языка. В шаблоне вы тоже будете выводить значение через `implode`? Предлагаю закончить дискуссию. Если вам не нравится ответ, вы можете написать свой и проголосовать за мой.

Comment: Побывал foreach. Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). В целом я хз - мой уровень знаний, а задача единственная, передавать через запятую если выбрано несколько переменных. поэтому тут и спросил с тем кодом который есть.

Comment: @ВикторМуравьев добавьте код, как через `foreach` пробовали.

Comment: Так echo $_POST['option']; заменил на ваш ответ

Comment: Меня ввело в заблуждение `$_POST['option']`. Вы назвали `select` именем `usert`, а проверяете, почему-то `option`. Я поправил ответ.

Comment: Не нет.. Я не настолько уж)) $_POST поменять это первым делом. Не работает ваш вариант. Интересно, может дело в версии php

Comment: @ВикторМуравьев, напишите мне в телеграм. Ссылка в профиле